# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare mb_str_split() in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\language_helper.php on line 39

Tags: php, laravel

```
 // Line 39 //

   function mb_str_split($str, $length = 1) 
    {
        if ($length < 1) return false;
        $result = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < mb_strlen($str); $i += $length) {
            $result[] = mb_substr($str, $i, $length);
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

**this is script laravel and i made install and get this error
can anyone help me to solve this problem ?**

Comment: function `mb_str_split` already exists. just rename your function

Comment: Can't have the same function twice, https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-str-split.php. `function mb_str_split2....`

Answer (score 1):

[mb_str_split()](https://www.php.net/mb_str_split) is a builtin function in all supported PHP releases (it was added in PHP/7.4.0). You can probably just remove yours.

If you want to keep it backwards compatible with older PHP versions, you can define it only [when it doesn't exist already](https://php.net/function_exists):

```
if (!function_exists('mb_str_split')) {
    function mb_str_split($str, $length = 1) 
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```